# Change Splash on Pi 4

Tags: pi-4

Halfterm is upon us, I've got a RP4 for my daughter and want to change the splash screen for her, but I've never used Linux based systems before and so don't know where to start. I've already got the 1920 x 1080 png file I want to use

Cheers,

Pete

Comment: Hello and welcome – What do you mean by "Splash"?

Comment: Much like how Retropie have their logo come up

Answer (score 1):

> I've got a RP4 for my daughter and want to change the splash screen...

It's the boot up screen and what it has configured. You can customize the boot up screen as you mentioned by [this link](https://scribles.net/customizing-boot-up-screen-on-raspberry-pi/).

However, if you want just add a simple picture/image, check [this link](https://raspberry-projects.com/pi/pi-operating-systems/raspbian/custom-boot-up-screen) out which is telling you to install `fbi` package.

Comment: Sadly didn't work for me, I now have a black screen until the desktop pops up. Seems to fall at the insserv command, says command not found

Comment: @PeterJames Yes, you can run `apt-get install insserv` to fix this problem.